# How to use pprint-newline properly?

Tags: clojure, output, pretty-print

I am trying to print a sequence such that neither the whole sequence is printed on one line, nor is each element of the sequence printed on its own line. E.g.

```
[10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29]
```

I found `pprint-newline` in the documentation which indicates that allows me to determine how the newline gets printed. Unfortunately, I cannot find any examples on how it is to be used in conjunction with `pprint`, and the doc string doesn't to offer much insight:

```
-------------------------
clojure.pprint/pprint-newline
([kind])
  Print a conditional newline to a pretty printing stream. kind specifies if the 
newline is :linear, :miser, :fill, or :mandatory. 

This function is intended for use when writing custom dispatch functions.

Output is sent to *out* which must be a pretty printing writer.
```

`pprint` specifies an optional second argument for the `writer`, which is by default set to `*out*`. However, I am not sure how to 'send' `pprint-writer` to `*out*` in this case, e.g. something like the example below doesn't appear to work

```
(clojure.pprint/pprint [1 2 3 4] (*out* (clojure.pprint/pprint-newline :miser)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Guillermo explained how to change the dispatch for pretty-printing in general, if all you want to do is printing one collection differently, that's possible, too.

For example, using `cl-format` (after `(use '[clojure.pprint :as pp)`):

```
(binding [pp/*print-pretty* true
          pp/*print-miser-width* nil
          pp/*print-right-margin* 10]
  (pp/cl-format true "~<[~;~@{~a~^ ~:_~}~;]~:>~%" '[foo bar baz quux]))
```

Set `*print-right-margin*` as you wish.

You don't have to use format for this. The format directives can be translated to their respective pretty-printer functions, if you want. Explanation of the format string: `~<` and `~:>` establish a logical block. Inside the block, there are three sections separated by `~;`. The first and last section are your prefix and suffix, while the elements are printed in the middle section, using `~@{` and `~}`. For each element, the element is printed using `~a`, followed by a space, if needed, and a conditional fill-style newline.

(In CL, the format string could be simplified to `"~<[~;~@{~a~^ ~}~;]~:@>~%"`, but that doesn't seem to work in Clojure 1.5.)

Comment: Thanks for the solution - it works perfectly. However, can you please tell me what you mean by the following: "The format directives can be translated to their respective pretty-printer functions, if you want". Would this entail writing a dispatch function as Guillermo indicated below? Perhaps that would be a better alternative to the arcane CL style `format` string...

Comment: There is a correspondence between the format directives and the functions in Guillermo's answer: `~< … ~:>` is `pprint-logical-block`, `~@{ … ~}` is `print-length-loop`, etc. Note that I'm using `~:_`, corresponding to `(pprint-newline :fill)`, not `:linear`. You *should* be able to use these functions directly for printing, not just for dispatching, but you'll have to set up everything properly, i.e. use `get-pretty-writer` with `*out*` etc. Just `binding` it didn't work for me, though. I had some success with `set!`, but that feels hackish, so check the documentation (or source) for that.

Comment: Thanks again. I might have to break open the Common Lisp hyperspec and read up on the CL formatting...

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, reading about the CL pretty-printer would certainly help. But while the Clojure pretty-printer is strongly influenced by it (XP), and the general concepts should be the same, there will be differences under the hood. (Like setting up `*out*` correctly, as mentioned above.) If all you want to do is print one collection, the `cl-format` solution should suffice. Sure, it looks rather arcane, but on the other hand, it's a powerful, compact DSL for formatted output. For anything more complex (e.g. a custom data format or language), I'd suggest creating a custom dispatch table.

Answer (score 1):

As the help says, the function is intended for use for custom dispatch functions.

In order to change the behavior of the pprint for sequences you need to provide a new dispatch function for `clojure.lang.ISeq`.

The current dispatch function for sequences you can find in `clojure/pprint/dispatch.clj`

```
(use-method simple-dispatch clojure.lang.ISeq pprint-list) 
...
(defn- pprint-simple-list [alis]
    (pprint-logical-block :prefix "(" :suffix ")"
      (print-length-loop [alis (seq alis)]
        (when alis
      (write-out (first alis))
      (when (next alis)
        (.write ^java.io.Writer *out* " ")
        (pprint-newline :linear)
        (recur (next alis)))))))
```

Since printing is dispatched according to data type overriding seems to be the way to go.

See the [source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/pprint/dispatch.clj#L66) for ideas.

Comment: Thank you. This seems like the way to go, ultimately. But for now, danlei's solution satisfies my requirements.